# Bootstrap 3.3 - rows in a column, nested downwards

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am beginner in Bootstrap, and I do not know how to do something I need.

I want to make this design.

[image]

The problem is that I can not make the DIV 5. I've tried several ways, but the most I've gotten is this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">DIV TITLE
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">DIV 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="border-bottom:none">DIV 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="border-bottom:none">DIV 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="border-bottom:none">DIV 4
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div id="heighter">
            DIV 5:<br>
            INFO<br>
            MORE INFO<br>
            MORE INFO
            MORE INFO
            MORE INFO
            MORE INFO
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">DIV 5
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">DIV 6
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">DIV 7
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">DIV 8
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">DIV 9
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">DIV 10
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">DIV 11
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">DIV 12
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">DIV 13
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">DIV 14
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">DIV 15
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">DIV 16
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">DIV 17
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/drlynch/1m8orsud/

Thanks

Comment: Please share a link to jsfiddle containing the code that got you to the second example (link)

Comment: Hi, Techtronic.

The link of my code in jsfiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/drlynch/1m8orsud/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea you can use. I did not do the full example, but you should be able to do what you want. The idea is using nested container, as in this     [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljbpy02f/):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">DIV TITLE
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">DIV 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="border-bottom:none">DIV 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="border-bottom:none">DIV 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="border-bottom:none">DIV 4
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">DIV 12
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="border-bottom:none">DIV 22
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="border-bottom:none">DIV 32
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="border-bottom:none">DIV 42
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div id="heighter">
            DIV 5:<br>
            INFO<br>
            MORE INFO<br>
            MORE INFO
            MORE INFO
            MORE INFO
            MORE INFO
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and assistance, Rémi ;)

The problem is that the same thing is still happening :(
Border-bottoms and border-left and right, not display correctly.
Example:
http://i.imgur.com/tCzLArF.png